# What am I missing working with UTAM and creating a record for an object utilizing Dynamic Forms?

Tags: javascript, test-automation, dynamic-forms

I have been fighting this for a bit of time and feel like I must be missing something painfully obvious.

To set the stage I am starting to explore utilizing WebDriverIO with UTAM to automate some e2e testing for my Salesforce org. I have a custom object (Home Page Messages) that I am trying to create a record at the start of a test. This custom object is utilizing dynamic forms.

My `.spec` file currently looks like this (I removed non-relevant parts of the file):

```
import { logIntoSalesforce } from "./utam-helper";
import DesktopLayoutContainer from "salesforce-pageobjects/navex/pageObjects/desktopLayoutContainer";
import ObjectHome from "salesforce-pageobjects/force/pageObjects/objectHome";
import RecordActionWrapper from "salesforce-pageobjects/global/pageObjects/recordActionWrapper";
import RecordLayoutBaseInput from "salesforce-pageobjects/records/pageObjects/recordLayoutBaseInput";
import FieldSection2 from "salesforce-pageobjects/flexipage/pageObjects/fieldSection2";
import Column2 from "salesforce-pageobjects/flexipage/pageObjects/column2";
import Field from "salesforce-pageobjects/flexipage/pageObjects/field";
import RecordField from "salesforce-pageobjects/record/flexipage/pageObjects/recordField";

describe("performs necessary home page message actions", () => {
  let domDocument;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    domDocument = await logIntoSalesforce();
  });

  it("creates, edits, and deletes a home page message", async () => {
    //Navigate to the Home Page Message tab
    const desktopContainer = await utam.load(DesktopLayoutContainer);
    const appNav = await desktopContainer.getAppNav();
    const appNavBar = await appNav.getAppNavBar();
    const navItem = await appNavBar.getNavItem("Home Page Messages");
    await navItem.clickAndWaitForUrl(
      "lightning/o/HomePageMessage__c/list?filterName"
    );

    //Click 'New' button on list view
    const consoleObjectHome = await utam.load(ObjectHome);
    const listView = await consoleObjectHome.getListView();
    const listViewHeader = await listView.getHeader();
    const newHomePageMessageAction = await listViewHeader.waitForAction("New");
    await newHomePageMessageAction.click();

    //Fill in the fields to create a new home page record
    const recordActionWrapper = await utam.load(RecordActionWrapper);
    const dynamicFormFlexipage =
      await recordActionWrapper.waitForRecordHomeSingleColNoHeaderTemplateDesktop2();
    const informationFieldSection = await (
      await dynamicFormFlexipage.getComponent2("flexipage_fieldSection")
    ).getContent(FieldSection2);
    const informationFieldSectionColumns =
      await informationFieldSection.getContent(Column2);
    const fields = await informationFieldSectionColumns[0].getFields(Field);
    const field = fields[0];
    await field.waitForRecordFieldContent();
    const fieldInput = await field.getRecordFieldContent(RecordField);
    const fieldLightningInput = await fieldInput.getFieldContentEditMode(
      RecordLayoutBaseInput
    );

    await browser.debug();
  });
});
```

I am currently receiving the following console input:

```
 1) performs necessary home page message actions creates, edits, and deletes a home page message
 Error: Can't find elements with locator '[slot='input']' inside its scope element.
 Error: Can't find elements with locator '[slot='input']' inside its scope element.
     at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
     at UserContext.<anonymous> (/Users/johnDoe/Documents/git/platform/utam3000/force-app/test/utam/hello.spec.js:54:33)
```

This lines up with this line in my test method (last line before my browser pause)

```
const fieldLightningInput = await fieldInput.getFieldContentEditMode(
      RecordLayoutBaseInput
    );
```

Has anybody had any success creating records for a custom object utilizing dynamic forms? If so am I doing something silly here? I have been double and triple checking the DOM produced by Salesforce and the UTAM files from the `salesforce-pageobjects` package and I am not seeing anything else I should be doing differently. It looks like it should be finding the base record input on the line it is complaining about.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: There is little point in e2e tests that test standard Salesforce features, such as dynamic forms. If your aim is to verify that your dynamic form is configured with the correct dynamic behaviour that can be done without using e2e tests but rather by comparing the underlying configuration with a baseline. If your attempt to create a record is purely to initialize test data for subsequent use in your test then I recommend you instead use something like jsforce to invoke the REST APIs to create the test data programmatically, leaving your e2e test to verify your custom UI behaves appropriately...

Comment: Initially I was thinking there would still be a need to interact with dynamic forms for testing something like actions done through triggers, etc. But in reality in that scenario a code based acceptance test could (and maybe should) cover that.